# How to Manage Multiple Status of same Table using SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

How to Manage Multiple Status of same Table using SQL query. 
I have two GridView to show data base on **EvaluationStatus** and **CertificateStatus**.

The Default value for **EvaluationStatus** is `Not Assigned` and **CertificateStatus** is `Awaited`.

In first GridView Showing `Cleared` users data correctly using below query.

```
 select * from MyTable where EvaluationStatus='Cleared' and CertificateStatus='Cleared'
```

In Second Gridview not showing correct data to show not cleared users but not getting idea to write that query, below wrote one query but not working properly.

```
select * from MyTable where EvaluationStatus in('Not Assigned','Cleared') and CertificateStatus='Awaited'
```

The second gridview query if user will upload certificate means status will change from `Awaited` to `cleared`. Then the above query not working because now EvaluationStatus='Not Assigned' and CertificateStatus='Cleared' in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional where clause using case statement -

```
select * from MyTable where 1 = case when EvaluationStatus = 'Not Assigned' and CertificateStatus='Awaited' then 1
                                     when EvaluationStatus = 'Cleared' and CertificateStatus='Awaited' then 1
                                     when EvaluationStatus = 'Not Assigned' and CertificateStatus='Cleared' then 1
                                     else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do also by below query .

```
select *
from MyTable 
where RegistrationId in (select RegistrationId from MyTable where EvaluationStatus in('Not Assigned','Cleared') and  CertificateStatus='Awaited')
or RegistrationId in (select RegistrationId from MyTable where EvaluationStatus in('Not Assigned') and CertificateStatus in('Awaited','Cleared'))
```